# erro "fimenquanto sem enquanto correspondente" visualg

Tags: visualg

```
algoritmo "semnome"
var
   n,i,ma,me:inteiro
inicio
   i<-0
   me<-0
   ma<-0
   enquanto (i<21) faca
      Escreval ("insira um numero inteiro:")
      leia (n)
      se n<0 entao
         me<- me+1
      senao
         se n>0 entao
            ma<-ma+1
         fimse
         i<-i+1
      fimenquanto
      escreval ("a quantidade de numeros maiores inseridos foi:",ma)
      escreval ("e a quantidade de numeros menores inseridos foi:",me)
fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código, você tem dois `se` e apenas um `fimse`. Ficou faltando o `fimse` para o primeiro `se`. O seu código deveria ser assim:

```
algoritmo "semnome"
var
   n,i,ma,me:inteiro
inicio
   i<-0
   me<-0
   ma<-0
   enquanto (i<21) faca
      Escreval ("insira um numero inteiro:")
      leia (n)
      se n<0 entao
         me<- me+1
      senao
         se n>0 entao
            ma<-ma+1
         fimse
      fimse
      i<-i+1
   fimenquanto
   escreval ("a quantidade de numeros maiores inseridos foi:",ma)
   escreval ("e a quantidade de numeros menores inseridos foi:",me)
fimalgoritmo
```

O motivo da mensagem de erro se referir ao `fimenquanto` é que havia um bloco `se` aberto, e portanto o esperado seria um `fimse`. No entanto, o compilador encontrou um `fimenquanto`, que não era o que ele esperava.

Comment: entendi, obrigado

Comment: @eduardo Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 